# smbpasswd resets password, but not expiry date

Tags: samba

I'm a DBA using VPN and SSH to connect to a client's Linux system, on which resides the database. They are primarily a Windows shop, thus my gig to manage their database on what I believe is their only Linux machine. (I'm doing a bit of sysadmin as well, but all simple stuff...) The VPN password is managed via Windows AD, but the Linux user account is not. My VPN password expires every 45 days, and their solution for resets is for me to call the help desk and ask for a new password. Besides the annoyance factor, I mentioned the lack of security inherent in that approach, but the client is unconcerned.

So, I did a little investigation, installed samba client, then tried and successfully used smbpasswd to connect to the domain server and change my password:

```
smbpasswd -r [domain.server.address] -U [myUserName]
```

I was prompted for the old and new password, and the new password worked.

I thought all was well with the world, but the password expiry date was not reset -- I had a new working password on day 43, but when day 45 rolled around, I was locked out. The folks at the client's help-desk acknowledged that they could see the password had been changed, and didn't know why the expiry date did not reset. They fed me a new (weak) password and closed the ticket. I went and changed that with smbpasswd, so all I'm left with is my dose of annoyance every 45 days.

I'd love to understand why the expiry date isn't being reset with my password when I use smbpasswd.

```
smbclient -V
```

Returns Version 3.6.3

Comment: That's an interesting issue, alright. I'd suggest that you [edit] it to include the output of `smbclient -V`. It may also be useful to include which version of Windows server that the AD domain controller is running.